# How can I use the trained image classification model in Sagemaker to perform inference on images upload through the web page?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, detection, amazon-sagemaker, inference

I have trained my image classification model using sagemaker and have deployed using endpoint. I have also create a web page that accepts image. Also, I was able to create the api. I am not sure, how to create the lambda function to accept the image and perform inference on the image. Also, should I include pre-processing steps in the lambda function.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not pre-processing steps should be included may depend on the algorithm. For SageMaker built-in Image Classification no pre-processing is necessary. In that case you can forward requests to the endpoint using Amazon API Gateway. See this tutorial https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/creating-a-machine-learning-powered-rest-api-with-amazon-api-gateway-mapping-templates-and-amazon-sagemaker/.

If no pre-processing is required, then there is no need to create a VTL template. You can configure "passthrough" content handling "when no template matches the request Content-Type header". For built-in Image Classification, make sure to add "Content-Type" and "Accept" headers to the "Method Request" configuration of the API Gateway.